# mvc change table column color depending on model value

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller

I have a table populated by my model as follows :

```
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 45%;"><%= item.UnmatchedAddress %></td>
    <td style="width: 45%;"><%= item.MatchedAddress %></td>
    <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;"><%= item.ReviewedStatus %></td>
</tr>
```

For the 3rd column i.e. ReviewedStatus I have can have 2-3 Different Values, and depending on the different values I would like to change the color of the background for that TD.

So I know I can do this by changing item.ReviewedStatus which can be 0,1,2,3,4 i want to have a different css class.

What would be a good way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to derive the css class right inside the view like this:

```
<%
    string cssClass;
    switch (item.ReviewedStatus)
    {
        case 0:
            cssClass = "class1";
            break;
        case 1:
            cssClass = "class2";
            break;
        ...
    }
%>
<td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;" class="<%= cssClass %>"><%= item.ReviewedStatus %></td>
```

And yes, it is preferable to use css class rather than inline styling.

Answer (score 2):

Using Razor syntax you can achieve this. 
Try below Code :

```
 <tr>
    <td style="width: 45%;"><%= item.UnmatchedAddress %></td>
    <td style="width: 45%;"><%= item.MatchedAddress %></td>

    @{
        var color = "#fff";
        if (item.ReviewedStatus == "Pending")
        {
            color = "red";
        }
        else if (item.ReviewedStatus == "Done")
        {
            color = "green";
        }
    }
    <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;background-color: @color"><%= item.ReviewedStatus %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Looks like OP does not use razor

Comment: Sure, but not razor and aspx simultaneously in the same file (in fact, in the same project).

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
@switch (item.ReviewedStatus)
{
    case 0: 
            <td class="class1" style="width: 10%; text-align: center;"><%= item.ReviewedStatus %</td>
             break;
    case 1: 
             <td class="class2" style="width: 10%; text-align: center;"><%= item.ReviewedStatus %</td>
             break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `item.ReviewedStatusColor` and do it like

```
<td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; background-color:@(item.ReviewedStatusColor);">@item.ReviewedStatus</td>
```

P.S.: It's in razor syntax; I am not sure how to do it in web pages syntax.